# How To Text Align Left And Center In Screen

Tags: html, css

I'm missing something simple. I have an `ul` with 3 `li` in it, and as of right now, it's resting against the left side of it's container. I want the lis to maintain their `text-align: left` look, but I want them to be centered horizontally in the div.

**Note:** *I would like to veer away from tables*
*And I would like to avoid widths that need to be adjusted at various screen sizes*

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {width: 100%}
ul {
    border: dashed 1px rgb(0,0,100);
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
ul > li {
    background-color:#cccccc;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
    border-top:1px solid white;
    padding: 1% 0;
}
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/uqkhcktj/

*With The Desired Effect, but Without Using A Set Width* http://jsfiddle.net/uqkhcktj/2/

Comment: It's not clear how this is supposed to look. Are they supposed to be *next* to each other in a line and equal width or somthing?

Comment: Sorry Paulie. They are suppose to look like they do now, just in the center. I'll make a picture really fast though

Comment: More like this, but without using a fixed width: http://jsfiddle.net/uqkhcktj/2/

Comment: You can't align left to one side or the other if the element is is the same width as the text....it's not logical. Either assign a width or just padding-right only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really want is to center the container of the list without an absolute width (should automatically fits the list width);

Just set your container's width to auto and use `display:inline-block;` so the container can grow as much as needed. After that just center the container within the parent, and force the list `text-align` to left so it doesn't inherit the centralized alignment from it's parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/uqkhcktj/5/

```
div#parent {
    text-align:center;
}
div#container {
    display:inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
ul {
    text-align:left;
    border: dashed 1px rgb(0,0,100);
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I also found an alternative solution: I gave the div container `display: flex`. I was going to add `justify-content: center`, but it doesn't appear to be necessary.

Comment: @CSSApprentice Flex is an option too, but you should be aware that it is kinda of new stuff, so pay attention to [which browsers versions already support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you need the li to be any specific width, but a way to do this would be with margin:auto

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uqkhcktj/3/

html

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
div {width: 100%}
div li
{
    width:50%;
    margin:auto;
}
ul {
    border: dashed 1px rgb(0,0,100);
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
ul > li {
    background-color:#cccccc;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
    border-top:1px solid white;
    padding: 1% 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're  wanting something like that and to still retain the full width look you could add a span to the html so you can center the words specifically.
You need to set a width and do margin:0 auto to center them.

Js Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7mgp4srk/1/

Html:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><span>One</span></li>
        <li><span>Two</span></li>
        <li><span>Three</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Css:

```
div {width: 100%}
ul {
    border: dashed 1px rgb(0,0,100);
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
ul > li {
    background-color:#cccccc;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
    border-top:1px solid white;
    padding: 1% 0;
}

ul > li span {
    width:20%;
    margin:0 auto; 
    display:block;
}
```